# Switch default network printer based on IP address

Tags: batch-file, printing

I have a batch script that simply switches the default network printer but would like to switch it only if am at home not at the office and want to do this based on IP address.

**rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n \mynetwork\printer1**

- The above line succesfully changes the default printer to the one I want if I double click it. But, what I would like is to place this in my start up folder and for it to execute only say when the **external IP address** (not NAT) is "30.30.30.100" and not execute for anything else.

Comment: You can use either of the following to get your IP address: `curl icanhazip.com` or `curl ident.me`

Comment: This is on windows and I would like to use batch script not sure if "curl" exists

Comment: It's here http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not very efficient but should work :

```
tracert  -w 30 -h 4 8.8.8.8 |find "30.30.30.100"
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n \mynetwork\printer1
```

Comment: Thank you this was a great way of doing this but for some reason I did not return my external IP address which was weird maybe because I am running this script from a virtual environment.

Comment: try to allow more host ( `-h` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the input really appreciate it I got it to work and this is what I did:

powershell -Command "$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient; $wc.DownloadString('http://myexternalip.com/raw')">"\networkfolderpath\ip.txt"

set /p extip= < "\networkfolderpath\ip.txt"
del /q "\networkfolderpath\ip.txt"

IF %extip% == 40.1.90.20 (rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n \mynetwork\printername)